# Type unit does not have null as a proper value

Tags: f#

Below I post a fragment of my F# program that causes problems.

```
...
match words with
        | name :: "of" :: context :: "=" :: value :: _ when Double.TryParse(value) |> fst ->
            let var = new FuzzyVariable(name, context, Double.Parse value)
            fuzzyVars <- var :: fuzzyVars
```

In line:

```
fuzzyVars <- var :: fuzzyVars
```

I get "Type unit does not have null as a proper value" error. I am fairly new to F# programming and I don't quite know what might be causing this issue.

fuzzyVars is of type FuzzyVariable list. FuzzyVariable is a custom defined type.

EDIT.

As @Tomas Petricek pointed out there was a line in my code that returned null:

```
| [] -> null
```

My intention was to ignore value of the match. The proper way to do it is:

```
| [] -> ()
```

After that change everything works fine.

Comment: @mydogisbox This is a compilation error.

Comment: Oh, heh, right you are.

Comment: `fuzzyVars <- var :: fuzzyVars` returns type unit.  What are you doing with the return value of the match?

Comment: @mydogisbox Nothing. The intended purpose of this line: fuzzyVars <- var :: fuzzyVars is to append var to the list fuzzyVars. I don't get it why it doesn't work.

Comment: Is this possible for expression var :: fuzzyVars to return null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned, the problem is not in the piece of code you posted - it looks like some other part of your program makes the F# compiler think that the expression `fuzzyVars <- var :: fuzzyVars` should have a type that admits `null` (but that's not the case, because it returns `unit`).

I was able to get the same error by writing:

```
open System

type FuzzyVariable(a:string, b:string, c:float) =
  member x.A = ""
let mutable fuzzyVars : (FuzzyVariable list) = []
let words = [null; "of"; "context"; "="; "5"]
```

And the main part:

```
null = (match words with
        | name :: "of" :: context :: "=" :: value :: _ when Double.TryParse(value) |> fst ->
            let var = new FuzzyVariable(name, context, Double.Parse value)
            fuzzyVars <- var :: fuzzyVars)
```

You probably do not have something like this in your code :-) but perhaps the error message might give you a pointer to where the `null` comes from. Here, I get:

> error FS0001: The type 'unit' does not have 'null' as a proper value. See also C:\Users\Tomas\AppData\Local\Temp\~vs648E.fsx(8,0)-(8,4).

And the code on line 8 between character 0 and 4 is the `null` value! So perhaps check out whether the error message gives you some more information? Or try looking for `null` elsewhere in your code... (It might be also caused by some unexpected indentation.)

Comment: Spot on! There was a line that returned null: | [] -> null.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it compiled just fine:

```
open System
type test = {Name:string}
let mutable fuzzyVars : (test list) = []
match [null; "of"; "context"; "="; "5"] with
        | name :: "of" :: context :: "=" :: value :: _ when Double.TryParse(value) |> fst ->
            let var = {Name=name}
            fuzzyVars <- var :: fuzzyVars
        | a -> a |> ignore
```

The problem isn't in this section of code.

Comment: initialization looks like this: let mutable fuzzyVars : (FuzzyVariable list) = []

Comment: Does your error (in the errors windows) have little arrows pointing to the problem (like I do above)?

Comment: Can you post some of the details of how you declare `FuzzyVariable`?